# Use a dependency from Private Package registry in another project in maven

Tags: maven, gitlab, repository

I am using Gitlab CI to generate a Package in private project to Package Registry.
In another project, I am using this package as a dependency and It tell me that:

Cannot resolve fr.drevit.rpg_core:RPG-Core:1.0

My settings are the following:

Pom.xml of the depending project:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/26858655/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
......
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/26858655/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/26858655/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
......
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.drevit.rpg_core</groupId>
    <artifactId>RPG-Core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Settings.xml:

```
<server>
  <id>gitlab-maven</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
      <property>
        <name>Private-Token</name>
        <value>TOKEN</value>
      </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

I don't know how to resolve my issue and I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work :/

Comment: You sure that another project can access the project's package registry? Perhaps have look at a group-level package registry or instance level.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` is limited to the project for which the job is running. In order to allow access to a different project, go that projects *CI/CD Settings* and add the project from which you want to access the registry under *Token Access*.